# How to set columns width in datasheet view in access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a small problem! ...  I set the new columns width in Datasheet view, then I save and close it.
but after re-open the Form in Datasheet mode, the columns width (all columns) returned to previous amount !!

is there any solution for solving it?

Many thank you,,

Kasra

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Access when using a datasheet. The fix I found was to right-click the datasheet (or from the ribbon), unhide columns then uncheck a field and then re-check the same field.  Then save the datasheet and the columns will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for a Form that its name is "Contact" to set all columns Width in "Best Fit" (in Datasheet view) but it does not work:

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Forms!Contact

If Right$(ctl.Name, 6) <> "_Label" Then

ctl.ColumnWidth = -2

End If

Next ctl
```

what is wrong? please ...